# Getting existing rotational value in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, dxf, angles

I have one DXF file for and I loaded in QGIS canvas.

In attribute table I did not found any angle for label.

How can we know the existing angle in which the label displayed?

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187029/label-rotation-values-in-dxf-imported-into-qgis

Answer (score 1):

If your labels are of type "Single Line Text" (Text) you can use the plugin "[DXF2Shape Converter](http://gis.makobo.de/en_qgis-dxfimport-dxf2shape/)". When you use the plugin, make sure to check "Export Text Labels". This results in 2 new layers: one with points for text labels and another for the rest of the drawing. In the Text Layer, you get the field "angle", that has the rotation in radians. To convert it to the unit QGIS uses, you can use the formula: `"angle"* 180/pi()`.

If your labels are "Multiline Text" (MText), they get lost in the process above. So you first have to convert MTexts to Texts using the "Explode" command in AutoCAD or another CAD program, to use the "DXF2Shape Converter" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin "***Another*** DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter". This PlugIn make that all automaticly:
Label(Text) with the correct angle and format attributes